# how the search engines interpret the exclamation mark in the url

Tags: php, url, search-engines

I wonder how the search engines - Yahoo, bing, google ... - interpret the exclamation mark (!) in the url:

- www.site.com/product!651031
- www.site.com/category!651031

I could not find documentation on this topic

Comment: Documentation for URLs is [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), for HTTP specifically, see [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.2).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably meaning the thingy [documented by Google](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html). It's called hash fragments or hash bangs (among other names), and it's [very bad UI practice](http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs) -- amongst other reasons, because a URI is permanent, and this lands you with a single url for your entire site.

Comment: I understand, but do not intend to do as twitter or facebook using /!#/


www.site.com/product!651031
this case would be a dynamic content-based ID `651031`
I wonder if it would be interpreted as www.site.com/product/651031

thanks

Comment: Yes, it's a valid url character. As is `:` which you occasionally find like `/foo/page:2/`